# Convert python object to list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to convert a sqlalchemy object to a list of lists:

I've tried doing:

`lambda q: [location.name for obj in q.all()]`

and it worked.

But when I wanted to add/append another one to a list, it breaks:

`lambda q: [(location.name, obj.name for obj, location in q.all()]`

This is what I wanted it to be:

`lambda q: [
[location.name, str(obj.flowrate)]
for obj, location in q.all()]`

Expected output:

```
[
    ['location name','10.0'],
    ['another location','20.15']
]
```

Update:

```
qry = db.Session.query(db.Log, db.Location).\
    filter(db.Log.location_id == db.Location.id).\
    filter(db.Log.location_id == id)

    helpers.write_csv_from_query(resp, qry, falcon.HTTP_200, header,
     lambda q: [
          [location.name, str(obj.flowrate)] 
     for obj,location in q.all()])
```

The function that handles the object-query:

```
def write_csv_from_query(resp, query, status, header, result_func):
    """Writes CSV response."""
    csv_name = date_to_str(datetime.now()) + ".csv"
    csv_header = ','.join(header) + "\n"
    # csv_data = convert_to_csv(result_func(query))
    csv_data = []
    csv_data = result_func(query)
    csv_data = ','.join(csv_data)

    resp.status = status
    resp.content_type = 'text/csv'
    resp.set_header('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + csv_name)
    resp.body = csv_header + csv_data
```

Comment: In `lambda q: [(location.name, obj.name for obj, location in q.all()]` the bracket before `location.name` doesn't have a closing bracket

Comment: what's the Traceback error message?

Comment: In your first example, `q.all()` iterates over `obj` (i.e., it returns an obj each time). In your second example, it now iterates over `obj, location`: two items. That doesn't make sense, unless you've changed `q` in the mean time.

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور ('TypeError', ['sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found'])

Comment: Perhaps I didn't completely explain what I'm trying to achieve.
https://gist.github.com/d30jeff/92829f8429a0fd48b3f7
Here's the code for the functions and also the file that make the API call, note that the commented line works, but the code looks ugly and I'm trying to make it more pythonic

Comment: You can update your question with that gist (at least with the last function): it's not that long, and makes the question self consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Since in the first example, `location` appears separate from the lambda (your iterating variable is called `obj`, I  assume `location` is some external variable (external to `q` and your lambda), and you should simply do

```
lambda q: [(location.name, obj.name for obj in q.all()]
```

or for your final example:

```
lambda q: [[location.name, str(obj.flowrate)] for obj in q.all()]
```

or, since `obj.name` seems to be equivalent to `location.name` (this is from the commented-out part in your linked gist):

```
lambda q: [[obj.name, str(obj.flowrate)] for obj in q.all()]
```

or even (in case of linked tables):

```
lambda q: [[obj.location.name, str(obj.flowrate)] for obj in q.all()]
```

(I can't really tell what is the correct formulation from what you've given, but I guess it's one of these.)

---

Summary: iterate over one (1) object only, and extract the information from that single object.